# VBA to Rename Workbooks in Folder with Corrupted Files

Tags: excel, vba

I want to rename around 2000 workbooks by the name of the author & a Counter.
Some of the workbooks are corrupted however will produce an error on opening.

How do I edit my code to get around this when the error inevitably pops up?

Also, can I open the workbook as read/write? 
the code bugs out and wont let me save as it says the file is read only.

```
Sub RenameExcelFilesbyAuthor()


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim Counter As Integer

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
.Title = "C:\Users\Logan\Documents\Excel Folder"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
'NextCode:
 myPath = myPath
 If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

 'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xlxs*"

 'Target Path with Ending Extention
 myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

 Counter = 1

 'Loop through each Excel file in folder
 Do While myFile <> ""
  ReadOnly = False
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
     Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        wb.Close
    Else
    Counter = Counter + 1
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents

   'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
     wb.Name = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Author") & Counter

   'Save and Close Workbook
     wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

   'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
     DoEvents
    End If

   'Get next file name
     myFile = Dir

 Loop

 'Message Box when tasks are completed
 MsgBox "Task Complete!"

 'ResetSettings:
 'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know how to add that to a while loop or how to close the error message when excel says its corrupted

Answer (score 0):

When handling specific errors, you should wrap the error handler as tightly around the potential error as possible.  That way other errors will still be exposed. Note that there is more than one reason why a file might not open.

Something like

```
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
Counter = 0

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        ' there was an error
    Else
        Counter = Counter + 1

        'Your code here
    End If

    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edited my code to reflect those changes. Does that look right? Also, is there a way to open the  workbooks as read/write as my code bugs out when trying to save because it says they are read only.

Answer (score -1):

Change your loop to a for each (you'll have to initialize myFiles using the FileSystem Object) and do something like this.

```
For Each oFile In myFiles
     On Error GoTo NextFile

    'your code

NextFile:
    Resume NextFile2
NextFile2:
    Next oFile
```

When an error occurs it will resume with NextFile2 the error will be cleared and the loop will continue.